# On which port application/process/service is running or at particular port(8080, 3306) which application/process/service is running in vc++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, wmi, msdn

hi i want to get information about application running at which port? or at particular port which application is running.. like at port 3306 mysql is running. i gone through all WMI classes in MSDN but could not find relevant output. from [Win32_Product] ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394378(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394378%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), [Win32_Baseservice] ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394073(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and win32_process i got almost all information about product, services and processes but still do not get port name.

Comment: do you only need the port name? (like 80=http)?

Comment: no not only port name like 80=http and phpmyadmin application is running on it

Comment: for the name, use the [C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\services](http://superuser.com/q/402715/57579) file or [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers). phpmyadmin will not run on port 80, but IIS will (using the system process).

Answer (score 0):

Try netstat from command prompt

```
C:\Windows\system32>netstat -anob
```

Also refer http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907980 for more information